# Hibernate: SELECT in UPDATE

Tags: java, hibernate, select, hql

I need do something like that:

```
session.getTransaction().begin();
session.createQuery("update Pack p set p.book = (select b from Book b where ...) where p.id = :id")
        .setLong("id", pack.getId())
        .executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

And have error:

```
Exception occurred during event dispatching: 
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [java.util.Set(BookKeeper.db.Pack.book) : BookKeeper.db.Book]
```

But why? `p.book` have a `Set<Book>` type, same as `(select b from Book b where ...)` must return.

Comment: what is the hibernate version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you observe

```
p.book = (select b from Book b where ...)
```

The select should return a unique value. If it doesn't then things will go wrong, because you get a Set on right hand side but the left hand side is expecting a book.

This is very similar to sql syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it might help you, I just digged in Hibernate Source code.

Your exception occurs inside of BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java
on the following place:

```
if ( lhsColumnSpan != rhsType.getColumnSpan( sessionFactory ) ) {
        throw new TypeMismatchException(
  "left and right hand sides of a binary logic operator were incompatibile [" +
   lhsType.getName() + " : "+ rhsType.getName() + "]"
   );
```

when rhsType and lhsType are the org.hibernate.Type objects:

```
Type lhsType = extractDataType( lhs );
Type rhsType = extractDataType( rhs );
```

now let's see what `getColumnSpan()` is doing:

According to Hibernate docs:

```
public int getColumnSpan(Mapping mapping) throws MappingException
How many columns are used to persist this type.
```

So according to this logic you can run such type of queries only on equal size objects:

if your `Set<Book>` `p.book` has the same amount of objects as `select b from Book b` returns, this query would run successfully, otherwise it would fail.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hm... same amount of objects... But it creation of Pack and his `p.book` column is empty. Seems to be this actions restricted in HQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - notice the max. Without that there is no way for hibernate to know that the inner query will only return a single row.

```
update Pack p set p.book = (select max(b) from Book b where ...) where p.id = :id
```

Comment: Actually, `select` here must return `Set<Book>`, not single row.

Comment: Else words - I need to add some books into pack. Tables have many-to-many relations. Now I just do it with two steps: 1) get books 2) set them to the pack. But it simple SQL it can be done simply in one query. HQL seems to be more complicated with same work.